# What is posting act tagging in transformational learning?

Tags: computational-linguistics

We have presented a novel application of transformation-based learning
to the problem of identifying postings in chat-room conversations. **Posting
act tagging** aids in the formation of models of social and semantic
relationships within chat data.

Here is the paragrape where i found the word. Is there anyone who can explain it easily?

Comment: Where is the paragraph where you found the term? Please give a link and a short description with bibliographic data (the link may go stale over time).

Comment: As the [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=00leMacqdCoC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=%22Posting+act+tagging+aids+in+the+formation+of+models%22&source=bl&ots=50NKRM3L3_&sig=vqth3294OIt4u3KfYfiWbZJTVuY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU-tPjkZLTAhUE5YMKHVV2DYYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Posting%20act%20tagging%20aids%20in%20the%20formation%20of%20models%22&f=false) makes clear this is the process/action of marking up transcripts of chatroom conversations with (presumably xml) tags which identify "posting acts" such as *greet*, *bye*, *wh-question*.